# Is it possible to change :after on hover, but not if the after element itself is hovered?

Tags: css, hover

Right now I have

```
class-name:hover:after {}
```

which works fine, but it triggers when I hover over the after portion of the element as well. Is there a way to make it so that the `:hover` CSS only appears when I hover *just* the parent element (and not the part generated by `:after`)? I would prefer to not resort to Javascript if it's possible to do it with just CSS.

I made a fiddle here demonstrating: https://jsfiddle.net/fthxb9z3/1/

It does the hover when I hover over the "hola", but I want it to only do the hover on "blah"

Comment: You mean in cases where the `after` element remains shown when you mouseout of the parent through it in cases where it overflows, like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/fthxb9z3/)? AFAIK mouseenter doesn't incorrectly trigger when hovering the area that *would* be occupied by the `after`.

Comment: Uh I think it's a bit different. To be more clear, I basically have text "abc" shown with `content` in the `:after`. It appears to the right of the main text. When I hover the main text, I want "abc" to change to "abcdef". But right now, when I hover the "abc" it also changes to "abcdef". I'd like to make it only change the text when I hover over the actual text, not the "abc" made from `:after`

Comment: I made a fiddle here demonstrating: https://jsfiddle.net/fthxb9z3/1/

It does the hover when I hover over the "hola", but I want it to only do the hover on "blah"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible.

`::after` is a pseudo-element and is therefore part of the element to which it belongs. If the `::after` is hovered, the element is hovered, independently of whether or not the `::after` is rendered inside the space occupied but its parent or is rendered in a completely different area.

When the `::after` is placed outside the parent, you could cancel the hover effect on parent by giving the `::after` `pointer-events:none` and effectively let the hover (and all other pointer events) pass through. But in your case they would pass through to the parent.

If you wanted an area inside an item where that item would not be hovered, you'd have to cover it with a sibling of the item rendered above it, using a common parent with `position:relative`. The sibling would have to be placed after the hovered element in `DOM` or would need a higher `z-index` than that of the hovered element in order to be rendered above.

Proof of concept:

```css
body {background-color: #ccc}
relative-parent, 
relative-parent * {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
relative-parent {
  position:relative;
}
hover-element {
  width: 10rem;
  height:10rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
hover-element:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
hover-element:after,
hover-mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
hover-element:after {
  right: -5.3rem;
  bottom: 2rem;
  content: '::after'
}
hover-mask {
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<relative-parent>
  <hover-element>hover-element</hover-element>
  <hover-mask>sibling</hover-mask>
</relative-parent>
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess at that point it'd be easier to just use Javascript haha

Comment: Actually, in this regard both `CSS` and `javascript` are about the same. AFAIK, you can't change the hover area of an element. All you can do is mask it with invisible elements so it's no longer hovered.

Comment: Ahh okay, I see. I'll try working with your idea first then. Thanks for the help!!